# Magento 2 checkout add select

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, onepage-checkout

I want to change City input to Select and populate its value or Alternative hide city input box and add Custom select and fill that option in City field
help me if anyone know.

Comment: What you have tried So far.Please start try with https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Inject dependency for country and region from your class construct

```
public function __construct(
        .........
        \Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country $_country,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory $_regionFactory,
        ..........
    ) {
        ...........
        $this->_country = $_country;
        $this->_regionFactory = $_regionFactory;
        ............
    }
```

Use the below code to get region collection in your form

```
$countries = $this->_country->toOptionArray();

$regionCollection = $this->_regionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addCountryFilter($model->getCountryId());
        $regions = $regionCollection->toOptionArray();
```

Create two field for region ( select & input ) using below code and add it to your form

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'country_id',
            'select',
            ['name' => 'country_id', 'label' => __('Country'), 'required' => true, 'values' => $countries]
        );


$fieldset->addField(
            'region_id',
            'select',
            ['name' => 'region_id', 'label' => __('Region'), 'values' => $regions]
        );

        $fieldset->addField(
            'region',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'region', 'label' => __('Region')]
        );
```

And within your form add a js file to perform show/hide functionality

```
$this->setChild(
            'form_after',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Namespace_Modulename::js.phtml')
        );
```

Create js.phtml file in your templates directory in view folder
like ( Module_root/view/frontend/templates/js.phtml )

Add below js code to js.phtml and save

```
<script>
    require([
        "jquery",
        "mage/adminhtml/form"
    ], function ($) {

        if(!$('[name=region_id]')[0].value)
        {
            $('[name=region_id]').parent().parent().hide();
            $('[name=region]').parent().parent().show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('[name=region]').parent().parent().hide();
            $('[name=region_id]').parent().parent().show();
        }
        var updater = new RegionUpdater(
            $('[name=country_id]')[0], 
            $('[name=region]')[0], 
            $('[name=region_id]')[0],
            <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Directory\Helper\Data')->getRegionJson() ?>,
            'hide'
        );
        updater.disableRegionValidation();
        window.updater = updater;

        $(document).on('change','[name=country_id]',function(){
            if($('[name=region_id]').is(':disabled')){
                $('[name=region_id]').parent().parent().hide();
                $('[name=region]').parent().parent().show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('[name=region]').parent().parent().hide();
                $('[name=region_id]').parent().parent().show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```